# Unable to find the Null pointer exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I am trying to slide the images on button click listener. I am taking new layouts for this. Each layout consist of different full screen images. on the click of the button the next layout should get displayed. This is my code.

```
public class ImageSlider extends Activity {

Button b, c, d;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_slider);

     b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.image);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            setContentView(R.layout.image1);

        }
    });

     c = (Button)findViewById(R.id.image1btn);
        c.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                setContentView(R.layout.image2);
            }
        }); 

         d = (Button)findViewById(R.id.image2btn);
        d.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_slider);
            }
        });
}
```

But I am getting Null pointer exception even after intialising all the buttons correctly. 
This is the error log.
Please help.

```
10-25 12:49:07.813: E/AndroidRuntime(13489): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-25 12:49:07.813: E/AndroidRuntime(13489): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fouractivities/com.example.fouractivities.ImageSlider}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-25 12:49:07.813: E/AndroidRuntime(13489): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
10-25 12:49:07.813: E/AndroidRuntime(13489):at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
10-25 12:49:07.813: E/AndroidRuntime(13489):at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
10-25 12:49:07.813: E/AndroidRuntime(13489):at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
10-25 12:49:07.813: E/AndroidRuntime(13489):at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-25 12:49:07.813: E/AndroidRuntime(13489):at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-25 12:49:07.813: E/AndroidRuntime(13489):at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
10-25 12:49:07.813: E/AndroidRuntime(13489):at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-25 12:49:07.813: E/AndroidRuntime(13489):at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-25 12:49:07.813: E/AndroidRuntime(13489):at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-25 12:49:07.813: E/AndroidRuntime(13489):at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-25 12:49:07.813: E/AndroidRuntime(13489):at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

XML file for main activity

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".ImageSlider" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="185dp"
    android:text="@string/image" />
```

XML for first image

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/a" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/image1btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Next" />
```

Comment: What line of code is it throwing the NPE on?

Comment: Have you declared the activity in the Manifest??

Comment: POST your XML. Seems like `b` , `c` or `d` may be `null`!

Comment: does all the buttons are in one layout or they are in different layouts?

Comment: @Scott Helme- There is no line number shown as such.

Comment: @Ezrou- Yes the activity has been declared in Android Manifest File. Buttons r in single layout

Comment: Are you not able to run this code? or you get NPE after some button clicks?

Comment: she gets immediately a NPE, since she declares only one button in her "main layout"

Comment: Are you sure that is the entire log? There might be another exception in the area after the initial logged exception. The second logged exception is the cause of the first.

Comment: this is the entire log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is wrong

you must not use set content view for image switching,

and when you setContentView another layout , buttons will be null

use this for all ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
     android:id="@+id/imageView1"
     android:layout_width="150dp"
     android:layout_height="300dp"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:src="@drawable/a" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

you can use something like this for MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


int[] pic_num = {R.drawable.img1,
        R.drawable.img2,
        R.drawable.img3};
int i = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            iv.setImageResource(pic_num[i+1]);
            i ++;
            if(i == 3){
                i = 1;
            }
        }
    });
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

In `activity_image_slider.xml`  did't have this `Button` `image1btn` and this `ImageButton` `imageView1` that's why that NPE came

Use `ViewPager`

https://github.com/chiuki/android-swipe-image-viewer

Answer (score 0):

I think you have mismatched the layout very first.
Set the **setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)** instead of **setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_slider)**;

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main_activity) //respective layout here
b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.image);
```

As the layout is mismatched the id is missing for respective layout and througs NPE